# An optimal order estimation problem for combinatorics background

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analysis, number-theory, combinations

def:
$\gamma(k)=\frac{\sqrt2^k}{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})$

$m_l$ are integers and $|m_l|<M$, $k_l$ are positive integer and $\sum_{l}k_l=k,\sum_{l}k_lm_l=s$.In other words, decompose $s$ into the sum of some integers $m_l$ with given bounds $M$, where $k_l$ is its multiplicative number and the total number of integers is $k$

Estimate the oder of $k$ for maximum of: $$\prod_{l}\frac{\gamma(k_l)}{(2\pi|m_l|)^{k_l}}$$

I come to this question when I want to prove a coefficient is well defined by the given expression sum over k.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This is a question-and-answer site. Please ask a question rather than telling us what to do in the imperative mood.